# Add CRAN mirror/PPA for R in Dockerfile

Tags: r, bash, docker, dockerfile, cran

I am writing a Dockerfile and want to know how to correctly add a ppa with pre-compiled cran packages for R.
My following code gives the error message:

> Reading package lists...
>   W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/c2d4u/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
>   E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/c2d4u/ubuntu/dists/cosmic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
>   E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I do not understand why he does not find it, although I can find the Release file [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rrutter/ubuntu/dists/xenial/).

My base image is postgres, which you can pull as

```
docker pull postgres
```

I encounter the error when I call `RUN apt-get update` after adding the PPA:

```
# Load base image
FROM postgres

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
    apt-get install -y apt-transport-https

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget
# More stuff here
RUN apt-get install -y r-base r-base-dev 

# add cran mirror
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
RUN echo "deb-src https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list

# add PPA with pre-compiled cran packages
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:marutter/c2d4u 

# install some R packages
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y r-cran-data.table
RUN apt-get install -y r-cran-tidyverse
```

If I would not call the `RUN apt-get update` he does not find `tidyverse` (but finds `data.table`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental issue is that the `postgres` image is based on Debain stable, while you try to add images meant for Ubuntu. I see three possible approaches:

- Use Debian stable via `postgres` image as far as possible and install the missing tidyverse packages from source.
- Use Debian stable via `postgres` image together with the CRAN backports for R 3.5 and compile *all* packages from source
- Use an Ubuntu image plus c2d4u (e.g. https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/r-apt/) and add postgres on top of that.

Comment: He still cannot install tidyverse or r-cran-tidyverse.  I thought it is necessary to add the apt to install all the packages!? Can you recommend another way to install it inside docker?

Comment: E: Unable to locate package tidyverse
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y tidyverse' returned a non-zero code: 100  or otherwise E: Unable to locate package r-cran-tidyverse.
I replaced this line `RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:marutter/c2d4u`  with yours.

Comment: Thanks! i took an Postgres Ubuntu image and continued with my own code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a typo in your Dockerfile.

```
RUN echo "deb-src https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

should be

```
RUN echo "deb-src https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/xenial/" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Does this solve your issue ?

Comment: sorry, but your suggestions does not work. Thanks anyway!